# Dump the contents of TLB buffer of x86 CPU

Tags: memory-management, x86, x86-64, tlb, mmu

Is it possible to get list of translations (from virtual pages into physical pages) from TLB (Translation lookaside buffer, this is a special cache in the CPU). I mean modern x86 or x86_64; and I want to do it in programmatic way, not by using JTAG and shifting all TLB entries out.

Comment: When your code runs, it would normally change the contents of the TLB. How would you avoid that?

Comment: The TLB dumped should be small to change the TLB a little. Also for not fully-associative TLB, there are some banking methods (assisted by OS) to keep application TLB not intersecting the TLB-dumping-tool's TLB (like page coloring).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linux kernel has no such dumper, there is page from linux kernel about cache and tlb: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cachetlb.txt "Cache and TLB Flushing Under Linux." David S. Miller

There was an such TLB dump in 80386DX (and 80486, and possibly in "Embedded Pentium" 100-166 MHz / "[Embedded Pentium MMX](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/previous-generation/embedded-pentium-mmx.html) 200-233 MHz" in 1998):

- [1](http://books.google.com/books?id=XZzUyvghwnsC&pg=PA579&dq="to+the+80386dx") -  Book "MICROPROCESSORS: THE 8086/8088, 80186/80286, 80386/80486 AND THE PENTIUM FAMILY", ISBN 9788120339422, 2010, page 579

This was done via Test Registers TR6 TR7:

- [2](http://books.google.com/books?id=yXriyj4eZ-gC&pg=SA3-PA19&lpg=SA3-PA19&dq="check+translation") - Book "Microprocessors & Microcontrollers" by Godse&Godse, 2008 ISBN 9788184312973 page SA3-PA19: "3.2.7.3 Test Registers" "only two test registers (TR6-TR7) are currently defined. ... These registers are used to check translation lookaside buffer (TLB) of the paging unit."
- [3](http://www.tecchannel.de/server/prozessoren/402224/x86_programmierung_und_betriebsarten_teil_5/index10.html) "x86-Programmierung und -Betriebsarten (Teil 5). Die Testregister TR6 und TR7", deutsche article about registers: "Zur Prüfung des Translation-Lookaside-Buffers sind die zwei Testregister TR6 und TR7 vorhanden. Sie werden als Test-Command-Register (TR6) und Testdatenregister (TR7) bezeichnet. "
- [4](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Intel/x86/Pentium/Embedded%20Pentium%AE%20Processor/MDELREGS.PDF) Intel's "Embedded Pentium® Processor Family Developer’s Manual", part "26 Model Specific Registers and Functions" page 8 "26.2.1.2 TLB Test Registers"

TR6 is command register, the linear address is written to it. It can be used to write to TLB or to read line from TLB. TR7 is data to be written to TLB or read from TLB.

Wikipedia says in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_register that reading TR6/TR7 "generate invalid opcode exception on any CPU newer than 80486."

The encoding of mov tr6/tr7 was available only to privilege level 0: http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/movrs.htm

```
0F 24 /r    movl tr6/tr7,r32    12  Move (test register) to (register)  
   movl %tr6,%ebx
   movl %tr7,%ebx
0F 26 /r    movl r32,tr6/tr7    12  Move (register) to (test register)  
   movl %ebx,%tr6
   movl %ebx,%tr7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of VA-PA translations stored in TLB but you may have to use a processor emulator like `qemu`. You can download and install qemu from http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page
You can boot a kernel which is stored in a disk image (typically in qcow2 or raw format) and run your application. You may have to tweak the code in qemu to print the contents of TLB. Look at `tlb_*` functions in `qemu/exec.c` You may want to add a tlb_dump_function to print the contents of the TLB. As far as I know, this is the closest you can get to dumping the contents of TLB.

P.S: I started answering this question and then realized it was an year old.

Comment: But this is still interesting. Which TLB is emulated by qemu? What do you think about using Bochs or PTLsim emulators?

Comment: What do you mean by which TLB? `qemu` is a processor emulator and can emulate a x86-64, sparc, or other types of CPU. I haven't used Bochs but the latest version of PTLsim uses `qemu` to perform functional emulation. PTLSim is for simulating timing information.

Comment: Bhushan, What are parameters of the emulated TLB?

Comment: It's a 256 entry TLB by default, but it is configurable. The definition for TLB entry is available at  (https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/cpu-defs.h#L81).

Comment: Does qemu do speculative TLB loads, like real x86 CPUs?