# Can I dump/modify the content of x86 CPU cache/TLB

Tags: caching, cpu, tlb

any apps or the system kernel can access or even modify the content of CPU cahce and/or TLB?

I found a short description about the CPU cache from this webiste:

"No programming language has direct access to CPU cache. Reading and writing the cache is something done automatically by the hardware; there's NO way to write instructions which treat the cache as any kind of separate entity. Reads and writes to the cache happen as side-effect to all instructions that touch memory."

From this message, it seems there is no way to read/write the content of CPU cahce/TLB.

However, I also got another information that conflicts with the above one. That information implies that a debug tool may be able to dump/show the content of CPU cache.

Currently I'm confused. so please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dump the contents of TLB buffer of x86 CPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803762/dump-the-contents-of-tlb-buffer-of-x86-cpu)

Comment: If you share your other source of information we may be able to explain why it's wrong / inaccurate

Answer (score 1):

I got some answers from another post: [dump the contents of TLB buffer of x86 CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803762/dump-the-contents-of-tlb-buffer-of-x86-cpu). Thanks adamdunson.

People could read this document about test registers, but it is only available on very old x86 machines [test registers](https://books.google.com/books?id=yXriyj4eZ-gC&pg=SA3-PA19&lpg=SA3-PA19&dq=%22check%20translation%22#v=onepage&q=%22check%20translation%22&f=false)

Another descriptions from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_register:

> A test register, in the Intel 80486 processor, was a register used by
>   the processor, usually to do a self-test. Most of these registers were
>   undocumented, and used by specialized software. The test registers
>   were named TR3 to TR7. Regular programs don't usually require these
>   registers to work. With the Pentium, the test registers were replaced
>   by a variety of model-specific registers (MSRs).
>
> Two test registers, TR6 and TR7, were provided for the purpose of
>   testing. TR6 was the test command register, and TR7 was the test data
>   register. These registers were accessed by variants of the MOV
>   instruction. A test register may either be the source operand or the
>   destination operand. The MOV instructions are defined in both
>   real-address mode and protected mode. The test registers are
>   privileged resources. In protected mode, the MOV instructions that
>   access them can only be executed at privilege level 0. An attempt to
>   read or write the test registers when executing at any other privilege
>   level causes a general protection exception. Also, those instructions
>   generate invalid opcode exception on any CPU newer than 80486.

In fact, I'm still expecting some similar functions on Intel i7 or i5. Unfortunately, I do not find any related document about that. If anyone has such information, please let me know.